# Illustrator CC scaling pattern in program but not in print preview or print

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an object with a clipping mask that contains a pattern. When I scale the object in Illustrator CC the pattern scales in the program but not in the print preview or actual print. I have scale strokes and effects selected in Illustrator, and have restarted both the program and my computer and the problem still persists. [image: screenshot of object in illustrator][image: object printed]

Comment: I'm having a difficult time determining *which* pattern is not scaling in your images... I see the same patterns, just one image is much darker than the other. Is it the zipper?

Comment: from the images it looks like everything is scaled correctly (even the zipper). What exactly is wrong?

Comment: The second image is what it looks like printed, the pattern inside loses all that intricate detail as if a stroke is being added to it. Its darker because our printer sucks. The first image is how it appears before printing, in illustrator. The same pattern is applied to other objects in the file and they are scaling correctly.

Comment: its scaling correctly for size, but the pattern itself isn't maintaining the detail it should.

Comment: Well loss of detail when printed (especially for end-user printers) has more to do with the printer than the artwork. Is it a printer with a postscript RIP? Are you sending RGB data or CMYK data? What the printer resolution? type? Etc.

Comment: I imagine some of it is the printer, but it looks like that in Illustrators print preview as well. Its more so that this specific item doesn't show correctly whereas other items with the same pattern are just fine.

Answer (score -1):

1) if you double click the pattern swatch square in the swatch palette, it will resize the pattern down to the original size

2) in preference > general > you can select and deselect the "transform pattern tiles" check box

- SIDE BAR

you photo above looks like you actually just have an image of a pattern in a clipping mask.(that is not pattern in illustrator terms, that would be a background image)

- to make an image into a pattern, drag the image into the swatch pallete and use that as a fill.